# Android javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted, Is there an alternative or Fix?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data in my android app. I am having following exception.

```
 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
```

at this line

```
         byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```

My code is as follows

```
 private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

 public static String encryptString(String str) throws Exception {
    return encrypt("KeY123", str);
}

public static String decryptString(String str) throws Exception {
    return decrypt("KeY123", str);
}

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
```

I am using `encryptString` and `encryptString` methods throughout the app to encrypt and decrypt data, I already tried converting 
        `SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");` to 
        `SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");` and vice versa but nothing helped me.

Are there any other techniques i can use apart from above technique?

Update:-

Added HEX
And if you don't know the solution or answer, there is no need to downvote just mind your own business and move ahead.

Comment: What is the value of HEX here. i am not able to compile your code without it.

Comment: @SachinGupta Added HEX, btw it is `private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";` :) :) :D

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957052/android-encryption-pad-block-corrupted-exception

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 have you found the solution ?

Comment: @AnuragPandit Nope, still haven't found answer.