# What is the correct way to use Cipher.getInstance("AES")?

Tags: android, encryption, aes

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES")
```

Android Studio's Lint complains about the above code as follows:

> cipher.getinstance should not be called without setting the encryption
> mode and padding

The above code works perfectly as explained by [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053311/355456).

Could anyone shed some light on how to use cipher.getinstance() correctly?

Comment: You should specify algorithm, mode and padding, e.g. `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. If you don't specify the mode and padding when instantiating the cipher instance, provider-dependent default values are used, which are often ECB mode and PKCS#5 padding. However, ECB is an insecure mode that definitely should be avoided, which can only be ensured by explicitly specifying the mode. Another reason is that cross-platform problems can occur if different providers with different default values are involved.

Comment: You should explicitly specify to mode and padding, for example: `AES/CBC/NoPadding`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html for the possible values.

Comment: @RichardHeap CBC should not be used without padding, and we prefer authenticated (AEAD) ciphers such as GCM for general purpose use.

Comment: Besides the points that @Topaco makes, you should also note that not specifying the cipher or padding mode doesn't really help readability. I'd even argue that it violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Finally, a remark for Hong: the goal of cryptography is **not** to make anything **work**. It is to **secure something**, which would probably "work" just fine without cryptography in the first place. So remarks like "the code works perfectly" doesn't really say anything.

Comment: Thank you all. @Topaco could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept? Using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" makes the warning go away.  This encryption is optional for the situation. In other words, it is nice to have some encryption. It is not a big deal if some spends to effort to crack it.

Comment: You' re welcome. I've turned my comments and those of others into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When instantiating a `Cipher` instance, algorithm, mode, and padding should *always be explicitly* specified, e.g.:

```java
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

If *only* the algorithm is specified, provider-specific values for mode and padding are applied, see `Cipher` in the [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher) or [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) documentation. This has a number of error-prone disadvantages and should therefore strictly be avoided:

- Many providers use ECB mode and PKCS#5 padding as default values, e.g. the BouncyCastle provider on Android (tested for API level 28 und 29). However, ECB mode is insecure and should therefore not be applied, see [Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946). To prevent the use of ECB mode, the mode needs to be *explicitly* specified.
- Cross-platform problems can occur if different providers with different default values for mode and padding are involved.
- Explicit specification of mode and padding improves readability.

The Lint tool points out these problems with its warning *Cipher.getInstance should not be called without setting the encryption mode and padding*. By the way, the Lint report also warns about the insecurity of ECB when it is specified with `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`: *ECB encryption mode should not be used*.

In contrast, CBC, when specified with `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, does not trigger a warning in Lint.

---

Although CBC is more secure than ECB, CBC only supports confidentiality. Therefore, [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), which provides authenticity and integrity in addition to confidentiality, should be preferred, e.g. [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). Since GCM is based on CTR, i.e. a stream cipher mode, no padding is required, unlike block cipher modes such as ECB or CBC (see [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)). Thus, GCM is specified with `AES/GCM/NoPadding`.

Here you can find a post regarding the difference between CBC and ECB: [Should I use ECB or CBC encryption mode for my block cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/225) and here regarding the difference between CBC and GCM: [What is the difference between CBC and GCM mode?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2310).

Finally, a little note about PKCS#5 padding: what is called PKCS#5 padding in the Java/Android world for historical reasons is actually PKCS#7 padding. Here you can find more details about this topic: [What is the difference between PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043).