# How to make 4 digit PIN to 32 digit to use it as AES key for encryption/ decryption in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, key, aes

I am using AES for encryption purposes in my Flutter mobile application. For the key, I am getting a 4-digit PIN as input from the user. But the AES key must be 32 digits for encryption/decryption. I tried using base64 encoding but couldn't get the desired output. Also, I tried searching for a secured random number generator with a seed (when a seed is given, the secured random number generator should return the same output) in Dart and did not find one. Can you suggest what can be done to convert those 4 digits to 32 digits?

Comment: Use a key derivation like Argon2 or PBKDF2

Comment: Look at the RNG in pointycastle. pointycastle also scrypt as a KDF.

Comment: Do not misuse a (cryptographically secure) pseudo random number generator as a key derivation function, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134336/9014097) (the article refers to SHA1PRNG from the Java world, though, but the warning applies in general). Use a KDF as recommended in the first comment, see [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/mac-and-key-derivation/modern-key-derivation-functions).

Comment: PBKDF2 works well. Thanks. I made use of https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography to achieve PBKDF2.