# How to use Cipher on this Method to decrypt a String?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, secret-key

Hello I build this 2 Methods the Encryption works fine but the Decryption get an error because 
cipher wants a byte and i want to encrypt from a String

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Test {

    private byte[] encrypted;

    private String encryptedtext;
    private String decrypted;



    public String Encrypt (String pInput) {


      try {

         String Input = pInput;
         String key = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345"; 

         // Erstelle key and cipher
         SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

         // Verschlüsselung
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
         byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(Input.getBytes());
         encryptedtext = new String(encrypted);
         System.err.println("encrypted:" + encryptedtext);


      }catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

        return encrypted;
    }



    public String Decrypt (String pInput) {


       try {

           String Input = pInput; 

           String key = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345"; 

           // Erstelle key and cipher
           SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

           // Entschlüsselung
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
           decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedtext)); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT WANT BYTE BUT I WANT TO ENCRYPT FROM A STRING
           System.err.println("decrypted: " + decrypted);

        }catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pInput;
      }

}
```

Comment: Encryption also uses bytes. So how did you solve it for encryption?

Comment: yes i know  but the bytes are converted into a String so i can use it and print it out but the problem is when i use the decryption it want the byte session from the encryption. But i want to give this mehtod a string and it store the decryptet text into a string to display the decrpyted value. I want to use this methods indipended in this version i must encrypt and decrypt and it will be work but i want to use decrypt without encrypting something before

Comment: Cipher encrypts bytes and returns bytes. But you are encrypting strings. So how did you convert a string into bytes before encrypting it?

Comment: By the way, converting the encrypt*ed* bytes to a string is *WRONG* and can corrupt the data. If you keep doing this, you will eventually encrypt something and not be able to decrypt it again.

Comment: please edit my code and make it i would like to see a code example :)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8828196/589259) if you want to go with strings all the way. You are currently using ECB mode of operation, which is unsafe for strings.

Answer (score 4):

Byte array cannot directly convert to string, and neither do the reverse direction.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class stackoverflow_test {
    private byte[] encrypted;

    private String encryptedtext;
    private String decrypted;

    public String Encrypt(String pInput) {

        try {

            String Input = pInput;
            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345";

            SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(Input.getBytes());
            //encryptedtext = new String(encrypted);
            encryptedtext = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);
            System.err.println("encrypted:" + encryptedtext);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encryptedtext;
    }

    public String Decrypt(String pInput) {

        try {

            String Input = pInput;

            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345";

            SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            encrypted = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedtext);
            decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted)); 
            System.err.println("decrypted: " + decrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pInput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] ag){
        stackoverflow_test test = new stackoverflow_test();
        String a = test.Encrypt("Byte cannot directly convert to string");
        String b = test.Decrypt(a);
    }
}
```

Result

```
encrypted:UmH+3eUagjrRDblxSStArnaktoxTLX+7qvPdwiTO7VggYmYtuXu/Ygww8ZG5SrDz
decrypted: Byte cannot directly convert to string
```

Comment: Thank you :) but is it possible to dont use Base64 in this Code because Android get some Problems with Base64 :/

Comment: this can help you, turn it into String of hexadecimal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Comment: then you must have design it in wrong way. What is the string you going to create to be the parameter of the decrypt function? You can read byte[] from file, from network socket, no need to be a String unless some alien can input xff in command prompt. XD

Comment: No :/ look if you make the Encryption and then the Decryption Everything works but if you just wanna use the Decryption "Only" it doesent go on it gives me erros...

Comment: @tom87416: This is a pretty good answer but you should change one thing to make it portable. Change `Input.getBytes()` to `Input.getBytes("UTF-8");` in Encrypt and change `new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));` to `new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted), "UTF-8");`. You need to do this because the default charsets may be different on different platforms and thus if, for example, you encrypt on a PC and decrypt on Android you might get the wrong answer.

Comment: @hanso: Are you saying you can't change the broken encryption code?

Comment: @hanso You didn't indicate Android anywhere. Besides, Android does have base 64 functionality in the main API. Is there any particular problem you are referring to in your first comment?

Comment: I cant use the Decryption only! i must use the encryption before to get this code working and thats not the solution i want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Cipher` to encrypt and decrypt a `String`.

```java
public class CryptUtil {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
    private static final String MODE = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String IV = "abcdefgh";

    public static  String encrypt(String secretKey, String value ) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
        byte[] values = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public static  String decrypt(String secretKey, String value) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] values = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(values));
    }
}
```