# Java AES improve safety, how long does the keystring need to be

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Encryption and Decryption in Java is still very difficult for me to understand. I have been using the following class and methods. I wonder how to improve the safety and how long does the keystring (schlüssel) need to be?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AES
{
public static SecretKeySpec makeKey(String schlüssel) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] key = (schlüssel).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
}


public static String encryptString(String text, SecretKeySpec schlüssel) throws Exception
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, schlüssel);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

    BASE64Encoder myEncoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return myEncoder.encode(encrypted);
}


public static String decryptString(String text, SecretKeySpec schlüssel) throws Exception
{    
    BASE64Decoder myDecoder2 = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] crypted2 = myDecoder2.decodeBuffer(text);

    Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, schlüssel);
    byte[] cipherData2 = cipher2.doFinal(crypted2);
    return new String(cipherData2);
}
}
```

I have been reading about the topic. But I did not understand how to transfer the ideas into my code. Any help is appreciated, please be kind with an encryption beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Is `schlüssel` some kind of password/passphrase or is it itself randomly generated? How many different possible characters (domain) does it consist of?

Comment: schlüssel is created either with SecureRandom or by user input. The characters possible are "0123456789abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Comment: if there is really a `ü` in your variable name (`schlüssel`) -> don't do it. even if its allowed, i wouldn't recommend it (name it `schluessel` instead)

Comment: Note that there is a site called [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Another remark; it seems to me that you are misunderstanding a lot about cryptography; I would recommend following at least a base course in crypto before starting to define a protocol, let alone to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to Maarten Bodeswes code I try to bring his code into the form I am using.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class AESplus 
{
public static SecretKeySpec makeKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
password = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1,password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    password = password.substring(password.length()-32, password.length());
    final byte[] symKeyData = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(password);
    return new SecretKeySpec(symKeyData, "AES");
}


public static String encryptString(String text, SecretKeySpec key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
                    InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    final byte[] encodedMessage = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    final int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

    // generate random IV using block size
    final byte[] ivData = new byte[blockSize];
    final SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    rnd.nextBytes(ivData);
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivData);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    final byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encodedMessage);

    // concatenate IV and encrypted message
    final byte[] ivAndEncryptedMessage = new byte[ivData.length + encryptedMessage.length];
    System.arraycopy(ivData, 0, ivAndEncryptedMessage, 0, blockSize);
    System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, 0, ivAndEncryptedMessage, blockSize, encryptedMessage.length);
    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(ivAndEncryptedMessage);
}


public static String decrytString(String crypttext, SecretKeySpec key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
                        InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
{    
    final byte[] ivAndEncryptedMessage = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(crypttext);

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    final int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

    // retrieve random IV from start of the received message
    final byte[] ivData = new byte[blockSize];
    System.arraycopy(ivAndEncryptedMessage, 0, ivData, 0, blockSize);
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivData);

    // retrieve the encrypted message itself
    final byte[] encryptedMessage = new byte[ivAndEncryptedMessage.length - blockSize];
    System.arraycopy(ivAndEncryptedMessage, blockSize, encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.length);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    final byte[] encodedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage);

    // concatenate IV and encrypted message
    final String message = new String(encodedMessage,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    return message;
}
```

}

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Lol4t0 The answer is complete !

Comment: I had to throw this solution out again. It was not reliable and I could not figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things wrong in this class.

- the class uses a cryptographic hash instead of a password hash - such as PBKDF2 - to *derive* a key from the password;
- you are using ECB mode encryption (the default), you need to use at least [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC), together with an initialization vector (IV);
- your class doesn't add any integrity protection, in other words the ciphertext is [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_%28cryptography%29);

It depends on the use case if you require the integrity protection. So I'll point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/992019/589259) for more information about password based encryption (PBE). Note that the answers may still deliver malleable ciphertext.

Furthermore the class contains the following Java mistakes:

- it doesn't distinguish between runtime related exceptions (missing algorithms) and input related exceptions;
- it uses the default platform encoding for your plaintext;
- it is using a Sun internal class to perform the Base 64 encoding/decoding.

Note that people will probably point out to you that you are using 128 bit AES encryption. That's however quite strong and - certainly at this point in time - the least of your worries. Upgrading to 192 or 256 bit AES won't increase security significantly.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Something like this? Mainly misplaced ')' really, but that was a small mistake giving huge readability issues.

Comment: I want to share the 32 character String with other people to encrypt/decrypt our data before/after sending it via internet. Therefore I can not use a secret key. Could you post how you would change the code?

Comment: If you already have a 32 character string you could just decode it using hexadecimals and directly use it as a 128 bit AESkey using SecretKeySpec.  There is a high scoring answer of mine that does it but I'm writing this on a mobile device. Check my answers on my profile.

Comment: I read your code. Sorry, your code is so complicated I am not able to change it to the form I have got above, meaning one method to create the key, one method to encrypt and one method to decrypt.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot extract the lines that declare & assign the `symKeyData` and `symKey` variables from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551263/how-can-i-convert-string-to-secretkey/8828196#8828196) and put it in a separate method?

Comment: I will try. I am using a plain password, that I can write on a piece of paper an give somebody else. I am not sure about this hex thing in your code. But I try.

Comment: Sometimes your codes works and sometimes the decrypt fails. What could be the cause?